# Flutter distanceBetween not accurate

Tags: android, flutter, dart, geolocation, distance

I'm using flutter dart for an application, I need to calculate distance between two points (and duration to get the speed..)  with Geolocator().distanceBetween() . However the results are not accurate , I barely move my phone from one point to another , but I get 40m or more as a result .
Anyone has the same problem? is there another way to have precise results in flutter ?
Thank you!

Below is an example of numbers that I get :

**I/flutter (29949):** lat 1 : *44.7954551* long 1: *-0.6206986999999999* lat 2: *44.7951915* long 2 : *-0.6211437*

**I/flutter (29949):** distance is *49.91697311401367*

Comment: Post the actual numbers for investigation - the source could be measurement error and not the calculation.

Comment: I added an example of numbers that I get

Comment: Interesting - the Haversine formula yields 45.74m.  In researching the dart implementation it calls the Location.java implementation which uses the Vincenty formula.  Haversine is spherical (haversine) vs ellipsoidal (vincenty).  But the difference of 5 meters over ~50 seems a bit large - but that's where I'd start.

Comment: Vincenty inverse calculator  yields 45.803m - so not sure where your 49.916.. is coming from - post the relevant code.  If your issue is with the magnitude of the difference in your test it again may be simply measurement error.  For that you'd need to understand what is the measurement source.

Comment: Calculating the distance via geolocation can be quite inaccurate sometimes, if not most of the time, specially if the service provider isn't very good. In the geolocator package, we have the `LocationAccuracy` enum, whose `best` supposedly has an accuracy of 0 to 100m for Android, which doesn't sound good to me. Now, if you perform an operation on top of that error, it's bound to go even higher.